# How to securely store service passwords with ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 membership for my site with defaults. Thus the membership password for the user is stored securely.

My service requires the user to enter username/passwords for other web services they use. I access those services from my service. If I save the users' service passwords I need to ensure that those usernames/passwords are stored securely as well so that if someone hacks my server they will not be exposed.

I understand the general concepts of how this might be done (encrypt the username/pw using the hash of the ASP.NET membership pw they've provided as the key).  But I don't know the specific APIs or correct patterns.

I also think it's basically impossible to really do this because if someone hacks my service they could simply use the hash themselves to decrypt the passwords.  Am I right about that.

Assuming i'm wrong, and it is possible to do what I want, assume my model contains something like this:

```
    public class MSExchangeSettings
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address for your Exchange account")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password for your Exchange account")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

Can someone please provide an example of how to do this correctly?

If, this is not possible I'll have to resort to asking the user for the PW every every time which I want to avoid.  Of course, for the services I use that support OpenID or OAuth I have other alternatives, but for this specific example (Exchange) I need a username/pw.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this

```
private static string GetPasswordHashed(string password) {

        var saltBytes = new byte[0x10];
        using (var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()) {
            random.GetBytes(saltBytes);
        }

        var passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);

        var combinedBytes = saltBytes.Concat(passwordBytes).ToArray();

        byte[] hashBytes;
        using (var hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("HashAlgorithm")) {
            hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(combinedBytes);
        }

        var PasswordHashed = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        return PasswordHashed;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you took posting this. However, I am not looking to simply hash the passwords. As I explained above I require to have the un-hashed password within my service so I can authenticate with other services, like Exchange. Thanks though.